# How to filter againts a second Observable?

Tags: rx-java

Say I have an `Observable<String> names;`

and then a second `Observable<String> bannedNames;`

Is it possible to filter `names` by ones which are not in the banned observable?

Currently I am converting the banned names into a list and then doing contains;

```
names.filter(n -> !bannedNamesList.contains(n));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there I'd say. You really should be putting the banned names into a HashSet not a List for better efficiency. Doing it all idiomatically with rxjava is a bit fiddly and not very readable and might look something like this:

```
Observable<String> names = Observable.just("fred", "dave", "sal");
Observable<Set<String>> banned = Observable.just("sal", "joe")
            .toList()
            .map(list -> new HashSet<String>(list))
            .cache();
Observable<String> okNames = 
        names.flatMap(name -> 
                        banned.exists(set -> set.contains(name))
                              .filter(b -> !b)
                              .map(b -> name));
```

So I'd say a better way to do this than your current approach is to use a HashSet instead of a list and not to bother with an idiomatic rxjava solution.